# Adding an object to nested array using Akita state library - Angular 9

Tags: angular, redux, angular-akita, akita

I have the next entity structure inside my Akita Store:

```
{
    id: 1,
    values: [
        {valueId: 1.1, data: [
            {dataId: 1.3, text: 'abc'},
            {dataId: 1.4, text: 'cba'}
        ]}
    ];
}
```

I'm trying to add another Object to the data array of a specific value, for example I would like to add `{dataId: 1.5, text: 'dfg}` to the data of the value with `valueId: 1.1`.
so the result should be like this:

```
  {
        id: 1,
        values: [
            {valueId: 1.1, data: [
                {dataId: 1.3, text: 'abc'},
                {dataId: 1.4, text: 'cba'},
                {dataId: 1.5, text: 'dfg}
            ]}
        ];
    }
```

I've tried to do the next thing but it didn't worked:

```
this.outgoingDataStore.update(1, data => {
    return {
        ...data,
        valuesByComponents: arrayAdd(data.values, {dataId: 1.4, text: 'cba'} )
    };
});
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It looks like you are going to have arrayAdd or arrayUpdate at a deeper level, The objects with properties `dataId` and `text` are in array property `data` nested in each object of `data.values`, such as `data.values[0].data`.

Comment: Im having the same challenge , have an Entity store with nested arrays, and trying to update the deepest level :) , in your case, an object in the data array .. @ Alexander Staroselskycould you provide an example with the solution you mentioned?